# Prevent empty JSON objects

Tags: php, json

How would you prevent empty json objects from validating in php such as `{}` and `{"":""}`?

Comment: Why? Validating where, when running `json_decode()` on them?

Comment: You can't prevent it, cause it's valid ... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to iterate over the object's properties. Stop as soon as you encounter one with a non-empty name. If you iterate over "everything" and don't come across one such, then the object is "empty".